# Insert a new span at specific index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert a new span element between specific index positions. So I am getting an html string from the database which gets displayed. Now before this gets displayed I want few span elements to be inserted between an index range. In the example I want to insert a span between index 6 to 18(World.This is)

```
<div>
 <span>Hello World.<span>
 <span>This is stackoverflow and it is awesome</span>
</div>
```

Expected Result

```
<div>
<span>Hello <span>World.</span></span>
<span><span>This is </span>stackoverflow and it is awesome</span>
</div>
```

The problem that I am facing is when index positions include different tags. I cannot directly insert a new span in the html string retrieved from db as this index range has 2 separate elements.

I am calculating indexes from the parent element.( div in this case).
What I tried is to search for the text included inside the index range, search for its position in the html string and insert a span there. But this fails when a word occurs more than once in the original string.( if string is "Hello world world" and I want to insert a span around second world, this approach will insert a span around the first world)

Comment: You're going to have to manipulate the innerText or innerHTML to construct the markup you want, before putting it back into innerHTML.  If all of it is still just a string, you just have to manipulate the string.  You haven't specified in your question what difficulty you are having doing this yourself, nor have you shown an attempt

Comment: Where do these indices come from? They are relative to specific strings inside different elements. Also what have you tried?

Comment: @charlietfl calculated from the parent element which is a div in this case

Comment: So you know the words you want wrapped? If so this is a bit of an XY Problem

Comment: Also suspect you got them from the `textContent` of the `<div>` but that doesn't take into account the other html in that `<div>`

Comment: @Taplar edited now it make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just replace specific words, then you could just use a regular expression:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')

const words = ['world', 'stackoverflow']

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`(${words.join('|')})`, 'gi'), '<span>$1</span>')
```

```css
div>span>span{font-weight:bold;color:red;}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>Hello World.</span>
 <span>This is stackoverflow and it is awesome</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The html strings are dynamic and index positions can also vary depending on what the user has selected